# How to find all the driver packages installed in my pc?

Tags: command-line, 13.10

I want to find or list all the driver packages(wifi,graphics,etc) installed on my Ubuntu pc through `apt-get` or `manually`.

How do i get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drivers are for the most part of the kernel. Some are built in but the majority are build as modules and loaded as needed.

You can list the modules in use with

```
lsmod
```

You can see all the modules with

```
ls -R http://www.bios-mods.com/kernel-version/
```

The discussion can become a bit technical, see : http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/

If you have drivers outside of those locations, in a non-standard location, we would be guessing where you put them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `lsmod`. It will show you drivers of your linux kernel.

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
pci_stub               12550  1 
vboxpci                22911  0 
vboxnetadp             25616  0 
vboxnetflt             27270  0 
vboxdrv               285085  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
rfcomm                 38139  0 
bnep                   17830  2 
parport_pc             32114  0 
bluetooth             158447  10 rfcomm,bnep
ppdev                  12849  0 

...
```

Comment: @bodhi.zazen agree but I did not see a better way using a system only. thanks

Comment: Perfect, I was not trying to give you a hard time, just add some information on modules is all.